# Load header and footer from Module in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, view, controllers

I have created a module in Laravel and im using views on that module, my structure is this:

Modules

```
 -> MyModule
 ->->Controllers
 ->->Views
 ->->->MyModule.blade.php
```

But i have the headers and footer done on resources->views->layouts->base.blade.php

So how can i call this one so i can use the same base layout in all modules? it is possible on Laravel 5?

Already tried this

```
@include('layouts.base')
```

but im getting

Trying to get property of non-object (View: ... resources\views\layouts\base.blade.php

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure of blade is relative to the `views` folder in the the `resources` folder.

Thus making your `@include()` have a structure like the this:

```
@include('DIRECTORY.BLADE')
```

and you can include your various blade contents by using `@yield()`

```
@yield('YIELD_FIELD_NAME')
```

If you are trying to have blades extent from that layout you would call that at the top of the blade files you want to extend off it.

```
@extends('DIRECTORY.BLADE')
```

This is an example blade file that can extend your layout if your layout contains the `@yield('content')` tag in it.

example.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.base')

@section('content')

  YOUR BLADES HTML/CONTENT

@endsection
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#defining-a-layout

How to add Auth middleware to controller:

```
/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

Here is an example Controller:
https://github.com/jeremykenedy/laravel-auth/blob/master/app/Http/Controllers/UsersManagementController.php

Here is an example of a view that uses that controller:
https://github.com/jeremykenedy/laravel-auth/blob/master/resources/views/usersmanagement/show-user.blade.php

Here is an example of the template that view uses:
https://github.com/jeremykenedy/laravel-auth/blob/master/resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php

Here is the routing file for the above examples:
https://github.com/jeremykenedy/laravel-auth/blob/master/routes/web.php

Comment: Great, thank you, actually the view is being loaded, and the problem is inside the view, so its working, now its time for php debug, not laravel related, thank you for take me to the right direction!

Comment: Thank you for this, so now, im getting an error with Auth, not being loading on Controller or View, im doing this on view:

{{Auth::user()->name}}

And on Controller:
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

This sintax works for all Controllers inside Http but not the ones into Modules folder, why? and how to fix?

Im getting null for Auth ...

Comment: Try adding the auth middleware to your controller in the constructer

Comment: Take a look at the constructor I placed above.

Comment: Inside module its redirects to application home when adding

public function __construct()
 {
     $this->middleware('auth');
 }

it is possible to use auth inside module structure ?

Worked on controllers inside Http folder but not on Controller inside Modular app. Im using this example to work on modular app https://github.com/kamranahmedse/laravel-modular-boilerplate/tree/master/app/Modules/ModuleOne

Answer (score 0):

Ok i was abble to get the Auth work on Module structure, just need to add this on your routes.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
  //Your routes
});
```