# How to load header and footer file in laravel

Tags: php, codeigniter, laravel-5

I am new to Laravel, I have had some previous experience with CodeIgniter, there I used to load hearder and footer like this:

```
$this->load->view('templates/header');
$this->load->view('home');
$this->load->view('templates/footer');
```

Is there anything in Laravel equivalent to this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43097804/load-header-and-footer-from-module-in-laravel

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `@include('path/to/your/file.blade.php')`

You can nest sections within partials as well, such as `@section('scripts')`or`@section('styles')`, just don't forget to include @parent with those, otherwise they will conflict with parent sections.